# Services bound to specific IPs don't start in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, boot, service, systemd

I have trouble getting nginx and dovecot to start on boot under Ubuntu 17.10. The errors I get are e.g.

```
dovecot[721]: Error: bind(2a02:c207:xxxx:xxxx::x, 4190) failed: Cannot assign requested address
dovecot[721]: Error: service(managesieve-login): listen(mail.domain.tld, 4190) failed: Cannot assign requested address
nginx[726]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [2a02:c207:xxxx:xxxx::x:x]:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
```

The IPs are defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`, the hosts are defined in `/etc/hosts` and if I manually start the services after the server booted, everything works fine.

I even tried adding an override using `systemctl edit dovecot` and adding

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
```

But no change.

Any idea what I am missing? The weird thing is that the SSH daemon is also bound to a specific IP and starts on boot without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the IPs were defined using

```
up ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 dev $IFACE
```

The problem is solved if the IPs are specified using multiple `iface eth0 inet static` blocks as defined here: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface